# Piece of Lua syntax that I don't understand

Tags: function, syntax, lua

I'm using a Lua-based product, I'm using their API and there is a bit of syntax in there that I don't understand.

What is this?
Is it a function call for Add, and if so what are the input parameters - there's nothing assigning that table to the variable input - no equals sign?

Is it a function definition for Add - that would seem odd, without any implementation and specifying what goes into the input tables?

Is Add a table containing tables?  I've never seen a table created with parentheses instead of curly braces?

```
serviceDefinitions.Add(
    input { name="p1", baseType="NUMBER", description="The first addend of the 
    operation" },
    input { name="p2", baseType="NUMBER", description="The second addend of the operation" },
    output { baseType="NUMBER", description="The sum of the two parameters" },
    description { "Add two numbers" }
)
```

Comment: This looks like validation or documentation for a service? We can't do much with the code you've provided, is there any extra context?

Answer (score 7):

When calling functions where there is only a single argument that is a table or string you can omit the parenthesis. From the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10):

> All argument expressions are evaluated before the call. A call of the form `f{fields}` is syntactic sugar for `f({fields})`; that is, the argument list is a single new table. A call of the form `f'string'` (or `f"string"` or `f[[string]])` is syntactic sugar for `f('string')`; that is, the argument list is a single literal string.

Which means that the following functions calls are valid:

```
somefunction({1,2,3,4})
somefunction{1,2,3,4}
```

Or, with strings:

```
print('hello!')
print 'hello!'
```

Answer (score 3):

It would have helped if you provided a link to documentation (or even the name of application), however:

```
serviceDefinitions.Add(
    input {
        name="p1",
        baseType="NUMBER",
        description="The first addend of the operation"
    },
    input {
        name="p2",
        baseType="NUMBER",
        description="The second addend of the operation"
    },
    output {
        baseType="NUMBER",
        description="The sum of the two parameters"
    },
    description {
        "Add two numbers"
    }
)
```

basically calls the `Add` function of `serviceDefinitions` table/class/struct/object with 4 parameters passed to it. Since, in lua, a function can be called without enclosing its arguments inside parenthesis in certain cases, the `input`, `output` and `description` functions are being called with a table as their parameter.

The results of each of these calls is then used as parameter to `Add` function.